# ViewState Data get cleared while doing multiple times (more than 1 times) Response.redirect on same page in Vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Page's ViewState get cleared while doing Response.redirect on same page with different query string.

My page is pure dynamic all the controls are created dynamically on user input so require to redirect on same page in each user input
While redirecting more than one times through  code execution my view state data get cleared

Answer (score 3):

ViewState will be lost if you use `Response.Redirect`
you have to use `Server.Transfer`

more information:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37753/Access-ViewState-Across-Pages

Comment: while i enter data in dropdown the page is posted back then in code again i redirect page to same URL but with different query string in URL through response.redirect through CODE but at that time my viewstate data get cleared.
I also try the server.transfer but facing the same issue

Comment: I am redirecting the page again on same URL(same page) not on new page